# Getting Error while importing docx module

Tags: module, docx

I have a simple program to read `.docx` files. But when I run it, the following error occurred. Can someone explain to me what the error description is?

[image: click to see the Error pic]

Comment: Are you importing a module into itself? That is unlikely to work.

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved the issue myself. There was a file named docx.py inside the folder where i kept all of my python stuff. Actually, pythons was import that file instead of original module "docx".